# detecting when a user opens a word document and when he types in it (in c#)

Tags: c#, office-interop, keyboard-events

i'd like to do the following : 
whenever a word document is open i need to save it in a way, and then if a user starts typing in it i want to save the time the document is being edited. 
i'm just on the first phase, and i can't seem to manage detecting when a user opens a document. 
i tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, but, in this way i don't want to start word application unless the user opens a document. but, when i want to initialize a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application, it's the only way i saw possible. 
is there a way, by using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word API to detect event of opening a file by a user ?

i tried the following (obviously it doesn't work, since it's just opens a word office application)

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application(); 
oWord.Visible = true;
oWord.DocumentChange += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentChangeEventHandler(oWord_DocumentChange);
...

private void oWord_DocumentChange()
{
   Console.WriteLine("DocumentChange");
}
```

also, i wanted to maybe use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, but couldn't. 
i started developing a method of my own, but its just seems to be a waste since this api is already build.
any help will be great.. thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have you looked into using a filewatcher to check for updates to the file?

Comment: Have you tried adding a macro to the document? That macro should have events for document open, document change and document close.

Comment: The difference between Office Automation through interop (what you're describing here) and an Office Add-In (what Ashish is suggesting in his answer) is whether you want your code to control the Office objects (Automation), or whether you want your code to respond to events during normal use of Office (Add-in).

Comment: thank you all for the response! much appreciated.  i did try doing it also in filewatcher. it does work, but complicated. i tried the com addings, while using this basic manual : http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=302901       my only concern now, is how to detect when a keyboard input is made from the user in the word document. i couldn't find for any events that can describe something like that, as i mentioned above, my end goal is to sum the time a user worked on a file.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already tried creating an [Application level Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx). That add-in should have all the event handlers you need to detect the first and last change to the document.

Comment: This is definitely an office add-in sort of solution rather than an interop solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could keep checking for open instances of Word every so often, and if you find one, then you use interop to get that instance.

You could probably use something like [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to check for instances of Word (or there might be some built in way of doing that in .Net that I can't remember right now), and then perhaps use `GetObject` to get the instance. This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902) describes `GetObject` vs `CreateObject`.

Comment: thank you all for the response! much appreciated.  i did try doing it also in filewatcher. it does work, but complicated. i tried the com addings, while using this basic manual : http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=302901       my only concern now, is how to detect when a keyboard input is made from the user in the word document. i couldn't find for any events that can describe something like that, as i mentioned above, my end goal is to sum the time a user worked on a file.

Comment: @dusm: As Ashish says, there's probably some events you can listen to for noticing when the user has changed something in the document. However, if that's not suitable for some reason, you might be able to use a [Keyboard Hook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) and a [Mouse Hook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) to see when something is changing, but it's probably going to be quite messy.