# Word Interop Catch Document Edit Event

Tags: c#, com-interop

I am trying to detect when a user edits a word document using the word interop.

I am aware that this even is not built in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_events.aspx

Is there some way to simulate this event or capture any edits some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you will need to add your own custom event handler.  **Edit:** Or use the Document.Saved property.

[How to: Implement Interface Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx)
[How to check if word document has changes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9f978a32-845c-4823-9780-2f184ba435a1)
[detecting when a user opens a word document and when he types in it (in c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072829/detecting-when-a-user-opens-a-word-document-and-when-he-types-in-it-in-c)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response!

I definitely agree that this is the road I need to go down, I'm more interested in how I would detect the event in order to handle it.

Comment: Read through all the information in handling your own custom events.  I have created more and more events to tie into other functions.  I don't know much about the word interop so I can't give suggestions off hand where to handle it.  My first thought is to register whether key strokes are happening to the document, but that will not register every possible document change that could happen.  I would delve into it now, but I am at work for another 8 hours.

Comment: My initial instinct is to tell you to tie the custom event any where there is a _changed(), _pressed(), etc method and check it against the original, or just assume because a key was pressed that the doc was pressed as well.

Comment: I don't understand where these _changed() and _pressed() methods are. I can't seem to find something on the document level that matches this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_events.aspx

Comment: I think maybe I could do something like this if I could find these methods:

`code` AutomationEvent changeEvent = AutomationFactory.GetEvent(word,"event goes here");
changeEvent.EventRaised += new EventHandler<AutomationEventArgs>(changeEvent_EventRaised); `code`

Comment: Let me approach this slightly differently.  What are you attempting to do accomplish, more specifically are you rolling your own editor with it's own user interface?  I have this weekend off, I'll do a bit more research and see if I can't pull some code examples out for you that might help a little more.

Comment: Otherwise the method should be triggered when a change is made (e.g. when a user triggers textBox_OnKeyPress() you would trigger the custom event handler)

Comment: When someone clicks my button in the ribbon, I need to know whether they edited the document since the document was opened. This determines which actions I perform on the document.

Comment: You know, looking through the interop it looks like your best option is to possibly use the ActiveDocument.xml or ActiveDocument.word, regardless you need to look through the "Active Document" and figure out which methods are being fired every single time the Doc changes (You may need to fire a custom "ChangeDoc" method that is tied to a "DocChanged" event.  If you honestly go through all the information on rolling your own events I promise you will start to see the possibilities with it and where you need to add the custom event to trigger what you need it to do.

Comment: I definitely agree that I need to roll my own custom event. What I don't understand is when I would trigger the event. Even if I had some sort of hack where I pinged the document object every second to look for changes, there isn't any method that allows me to know whether the document has been changed. Maybe I could compare the original active doc xml to the current one or something? This seems really odd though haha.

Comment: Everything that I am reading suggests using the Document.Saved property.  I'm adding some additional links to my original post.

Comment: And really it only looks like you will need to monitor the XMLNodes and Word methods under ActiveDocument, if you are looking to specifically catch changes.  I actually am wondering why you are not wanting to use the oDoc.Saved property as suggested in the above article?

Comment: Ohhh I didn't realize that the doc.Saved property would return true if there were no pending changes. This is definitely the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, glad I could help.  I would definitely look at the article talking about a documents "dirty" state so that it can be taken into consideration, apparently the document can become "dirty" or think that changes where made when it actually had no changes to it.